# get components of color in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, components, uicolor

Here is a code snippets for get RGB components of color. What can I do if the _countComponents is less than four, for example two? I tried to get components of color gray   [UIColor grayColor]

```
int _countComponents = CGColorGetNumberOfComponents(colorRef);

if (_countComponents == 4) {
    const CGFloat *_components = CGColorGetComponents(colorRef);
    CGFloat red     = _components[0];
    CGFloat green = _components[1];
    CGFloat blue   = _components[2];
    CGFloat alpha = _components[3];
```

Comment: What do you mean by: *" I tried to get components of color gray [UIColor grayColor]"*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The components of a color depend on the associated [color space](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/Conceptual/csintro/csintro_colorspace/csintro_colorspace.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001148-CH222-BBCBDGDD).

So `_components[0]`, `_components[1]`, etc are not necessary red, green blue and alpha.

Answer (score 6):

If you've got an instance of UIColor and you want it's RGB values, why not use the `-getRed:green:blue:alpha:` method?

```
CGFloat r, g, b, a;
BOOL success = [myColor getRed:&r green:&g blue:&b alpha:&a];
if (success) {
    // the color was converted to RGB successfully, go ahead and use r,g,b, and a.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**New Answer**

After re-reading the question.  To answer the Gray components question, the way you read that is via  -(BOOL)getWhite:alpha:

So you would do as per Caleb with something like:

```
BOOL success = [myColor getWhite:&w alpha:&a];
```

This gives you the gray value `w` as 0 to 1 and the alpha value `a` as 0 to 1

See the Apple docs [getWhite:alpha:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIColor_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIColor/getWhite:alpha:)

**Old answer**

From this SO question [how-to-access-the-color-components-of-an-uicolor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2690990/how-to-access-the-color-components-of-an-uicolor)

See the (rather old) ArsTechnica artical [iphone-development-accessing-uicolor-components](http://arstechnica.com/apple/guides/2009/02/iphone-development-accessing-uicolor-components.ars)

Comment: +1 Stop reading the questions -- you're making the rest of us look silly.